# requestLocationUpdates for provider and for criteria

Tags: android, location

Please tell me one thing

Here are two variation of requesting location updates

```
Criteria mFineCriteria = new Criteria();
mFineCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
mFineCriteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);        
mFineCriteria.setBearingAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
mFineCriteria.setBearingRequired(true);
```

if I do

```
String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(mFineCriteria, true);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, mLocationListener, null);
```

Then my GPS starts and everything is ok.
But if I just request updates with this criteria,

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(1000, 1, mFineCriteria, mLocationListener, null);
```

then I'm get results from fused location provider and gps doesn't work.

**EDIT**

Please tell, why requesLocationUpdates doesn't use GPS if it is a best available provider for the same criteria

Comment: I dont understand the question, do you want to know the difference between the fused location provider and the old location API?

Comment: so how do you know its not using the GPS?

Comment: 1) Every location in LocationListener callbacks has a provider - I log it.
2) geolocation icon in navibar (as of KitKat)

Comment: yes but the fused location does not say what provider is being used so again how do you know it is not using GPS. If you just want GPS location updates then only set GPS. if you want everything then use the fused location API

Comment: Well, I'll restate my question. Why subscribing for a criteria results in FUSED being used, while subscribing for one best provider with the same criteria results in GPS?

Comment: in LocationListener I log location providers, so I know when it is fused and when it is gps.

Comment: getBestProvider returns a single provider while you do not give it a provider in your second request so it uses all providers

Answer (score 1):

Just looking in the same problem somewhat, and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider(android.location.Criteria,%20boolean)) might explain it for you:

`public String LocationManager.getBestProvider (Criteria criteria, boolean enabledOnly)`

Added in API level 1
Returns the name of the provider that best meets the given criteria. Only providers that are permitted to be accessed by the calling activity will be returned. If several providers meet the criteria, the one with the best accuracy is returned. If no provider meets the criteria, the criteria are loosened in the following sequence:

- power
- requirement
- accuracy
- bearing
- speed
- altitude

Note that the requirement on monetary cost is not removed in this process.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can get information about which provider was selected

```
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Log.i(TAG, "AllProviders = " + locationManager.getAllProviders().toString());
Log.i(TAG, "Provider [" + provider + "] best criteria.");
```

Monitor:

```
AllProviders = [passive, gps, network]
Provider [gps] best criteria.
```

See also
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23425606/345810