# Android Location Client's Provdier

Tags: android, location

I am able to get location update or current location using LocationClient and LocationRequest.

But how to know whether the location is obtained is using gps provider or network provider.

Here is the sample code
https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible while using `LocationClient` and `LocationRequest` as the priority shifts from the source to the requirement/need side of obtaining the `location`.

The provider is **Fused Location Provider**:

> **Fused location provider**
>   The Fused Location Provider intelligently
>   manages the underlying location technology and gives you the best
>   location according to your needs.

Source: [Location APIs Android](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)

I tried to figure this out when they first introduced these api, even if you 'get' the 'provider' from the `location` object,
*i.e. `location.getProvider()` , it returns :"fused" as the value and not as GPS or NETWORK.*

Still if you want to deduce the source of location, not entirely accurate, but it can be related to the PRIORITY that is set with the help of [LocationRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html)

Example:

> public static final int **PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY**
>
> Used with setPriority(int) to request the most accurate locations
>   available.
>
> This will return the finest location available.

I have observed that depending on the PRIORITY set with `LocationRequest`, the use of GPS is altered.

**Only** for *PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY* does the app use GPS(not exclusively as its Fused Location Provider), hence for other two PRIORITY settings, it 'intelligently manages' the fused sources and provide the location with as much accuracy as possible, saving battery/power.

*Please Note*:
When set to PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, i don't mean that the GPS should be enabled to obtain location under that condition, just that if GPS is enabled, you can visually see that it is being used under that PRIORITY and is not being used when you set a different PRIORITY.

*The Fused Location Provider uses GPS, WiFi, Cell Towers, and Sensors to determine accurate location estimate.*

1. Have a look at [The Google IO on Location API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URcVZybzMUI&feature=player_embedded) , it was good.
2. [Useful presentation: Android Location](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Mf-fjZlLgBNz1nnLKEqES5Jp5s-fRSCuycPX6VphOEE/present#slide=id.gf0f531fe_00)
3. [Blog: of 2013, but useful](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/fused-location-provider)

Comment: welcome, the Location APIs - LocationCLient and LocationRequest is pretty good, find it better than LocationManager implementation, leave me a link if you get stuck with another question